# Pass PHP variable to Javascript and back to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I got a PHP variable called `$author_email` which I want to pass to a Javascript function which I call via HTML on button click`onclick="searchEmail();"` Can I pass the variable to Javascript but doing this instead? `onclick="searchEmail('<?php echo $author_email?>');"`

Then I want to use this in my javascript function to pass it to the PHP function it calls via AJAX.

This is the Javascript function `searchEmail`:

```
function searchEmail() {
  var admin_url = admin_ajax.ajaxurl;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: admin_url,
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'action': 'search_notify_email'},
    success: function() {
      searchNotification();
    },error:function() {
      searchNotificationError();
    }
  });
}
```

The javascript fires the PHP function `search_notify_email`
I now want to pass the variable to the PHP function. How is this done?
Which looks like this:

```
function search_notify_email(){
    $to = $author_email;
    $subject = "Test title";
    $message = "message message message message message message message ";
    $headers[] = 'From: Test <noreply@domain.com>';

    if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
      // Success
    } else {
      // Error
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_notify_emaill', 'search_notify_email');
```

As you can see my goal is to use the `$author_email` in the last PHP function. And the reason I cannot pass it directly is because this variable depends on which button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `searchEmail` to use the parameter:

```
function searchEmail(email) {
  var admin_url = admin_ajax.ajaxurl;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: admin_url,
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'action': 'search_notify_email', email: email},
    success: function() {
      searchNotification();
    },error:function() {
      searchNotificationError();
    }
  });
}
```

Then change the controller to use that parameter.

```
function search_notify_email(){
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Test title";
    $message = "message message message message message message message ";
    $headers[] = 'From: Test <noreply@domain.com>';

    if( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
      // Success
    } else {
      // Error
    }
    die();
}
```

There's probably a more WordPressy way to get the parameter, but I don't know WordPress.

Comment: But how is the PHP variable `$author_email` transfered to the javascript? Is this way of doing it correct? `onclick="searchEmail('<?php echo $author_email?>');"`

Comment: yes, that's fine. That's why I didn't put it into the answer.

Comment: But what I don't understand is how is this translated in to `email` in the javascript function?

Comment: When you write `searchEmail('username@somewhere.com')`, the value of `email` becomes that argument.

Comment: Maybe you need to read a tutorial on how functions work. This is basically the same in all programming languages.

Comment: So the `$author_email` doesn't need to be named `$email` ? Because I cannot make it work, I tried putting the `$_POST['email'];` in the `$subject` to test it, and it sends the email with no subject, so there is a problem somewhere?

Comment: Did you change the `data:` option in the AJAX call as I showed?

Comment: Sorry it was my typo! Got it to work. Thank you for explaining it all!

Comment: If I want to pass more variables, how is that done? Can you `echo` multiple to the javascript?

Comment: Of course, there's no difference. `onclick="funcname('<?php echo $varone;?>', '<?php echo $vartwo;?>')"`

Comment: You need to replace newlines with literal `\n` escape sequences.

Comment: If you were doing this in a `<script>` block I'd suggest `<?php echo json_encode($phpvariable);`. But that won't work correct inside an `onclick` attribute, because the quoting won't be correct. Perhaps you can move your event binding to a script, using `addEventListener`.

Comment: `onclick="funcname('<?php echo str_replace("\n", '\n', $varone); ?>')"`